# pentaho CCC Pie Chart with equal slices

Tags: pie-chart, pentaho-cde, ccc

I have a CCC Pie Chart which brings the years months (1,2,3,... 12).Don't ask why I'm using a pie chart for this. I want all the slices to be equal in size but also to see the values 1,2,3 in the slices values.The Sql (datasource) behind it is SELECT DISTINCT MONTH,MONTH FROM DB ORDER BY MONTH ASC.How can I achieve this? If I change my sql to SELECT DISTINCT MONTH,MONTH/MONTH FROM DB ORDER BY MONTH ASC, the slices are equal in size but instead of the normal slices values (1, 2, 3..) I have "1", the result of MONTH/MONTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! I used the sql SELECT DISTINCT MONTH,MONTH/MONTH FROM DB ORDER BY MONTH ASC to have the slicers with the same size. After that, at CCC pie chart advanced propertie, in the valuesMask field I entered {category}. See also http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?137038-how-to-put-label-in-the-pie-chart-outside-the-wedge-with-CDE